# Why the c#.net power operation results wrong?

Tags: c#, .net

Does anybody know the problem of C#.net in math power operation (10 base) that happened in the below picture?

[image]

I checked it during debugging. In the present step of while loop execution, the `counter` is 0 but the result of `10 ^ 0` is 10!

Comment: `^` is **xor**, that's why `10 ^ counter == x xor counter`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` isn't the power operator - it's the [bitwise exclusive or (xor) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-).

For power, you can use [`Math.Pow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow).

```cs
output += rem * Math.Pow(10, counter);
```

Answer (score 2):

in C# `^` is the exclusive or operator not power. Instead use `Math.Pow()`:

```
output += rem * ( Math.Pow(10,counter));
```

Answer (score 0):

`^` is exclusive or, and 0 is the identity in exclusive or. Anything exclusive or with 0 is just itself.

Answer (score 0):

**C#** doesn't have *integer* raising into power (`^` stands for `xor`), only `double` one: `Math.Pow`. If you want `int` version (if, for instance, you have `int output`), you have to implement it, say:

```
static int IntPow(int value, int power) {
  int result = 1;

  for (; power > 0; power >>= 1, value *= value) 
    if ((power & 1) == 1)
      result *= value;
  
  return result;
}
```

then you can put

```
output += rem * IntPow(10, counter);
```